I try to run spring boot in Docker but it not working it not found ./mvnw
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
LABEL authors="Akkarawit"
COPY . ./backEndAPI
WORKDIR /backEndAPI
RUN chmod +x mvnw
RUN ./mvnw clean package
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080

My docker file
Error
[+] Building 8.7s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                  docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 241B                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine                                                                                                              7.7s 
 => [auth] library/eclipse-temurin:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => CACHED [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine@sha256:9909002ad26c12ac3be05d258f6424cd25620042ab682358a5dfbfe866885846                                                 0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 1.67kB                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [2/5] COPY . ./backEndAPI                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [3/5] WORKDIR /backEndAPI                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [4/5] RUN chmod +x mvnw                                                                                                                                                                   0.3s
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN ./mvnw clean package                                                                                                                                                      0.5s
------
 > [5/5] RUN ./mvnw clean package:
0.434 /bin/sh: ./mvnw: not found
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     WORKDIR /backEndAPI
   5 |     RUN chmod +x mvnw
   6 | >>> RUN ./mvnw clean package
   7 |     ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
   8 |     EXPOSE 8080
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ./mvnw clean package" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127


please help me I try to run but it not working --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Is it possible you're on a Windows host and the file has accidentally gotten copied into the image with DOS line endings?

You are aware that this is not the way to run an application in Docker? Build the application locally and construct a container with the artifact or use a multi stage container, which first builds the artifact and then a fresh container to run the application. Or just use the spring boot support to build the image on your local machine ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image and presto you got a runnable image (without you doing anything).

That is not the only question when spring boot application is not up to Docker. Attached configuration has different username.
